# Is there a beter way to check input besides a switch case?

Tags: c#, optimization, unity3d

So I am running a Switch case to check if a user has filled in all the necessary fields within a form, and if not I prompt them to do so. I was wondering if there was a better way to do this, or if a switch case like this would suffice. General suggestions/naming improvements would also be appreciated.

This runs inside the unity engine, on unity C#

```
void CheckEmptyValues()
{
    /* Step wise checks certain Necessary values, if things are not assigned it breaks the operation
     * And prompts the user to fill in the appropriate slot 
     */
    int caseSwitch = 0;
    switch (caseSwitch)
    {
        case 0:
            if (GalleryName == null || GalleryName == "Default")
            {
                Debug.Log("No Gallery name assigned, please give the gallery a proper name");
                break;
            }
            else goto case 1;
        case 1:
            //This is a rectangle
            if (gallerySize.x == 0 || gallerySize.y == 0 || gallerySize.width == 0 || gallerySize.height == 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("No gallery Sizes assigned, please set some sizes before creating a gallery");
                break;
            }
            else goto case 2;

        case 2:
            if (buttonPrev == null || buttonNext == null)
            {
                Debug.Log(" Please make sure you assigned all textures before building, or you might end up with invisible buttons");
                break;
            }
            else goto case 3;

        case 3:
            //Location they want to get their images from (individual pick, or by path loading)
            if (!indvImages && !imgByPath)
            {
                Debug.Log("Please select a place to find images.");
                break;
            }
            else goto case 4;

        case 4:
            //Enable Bullet Buttons for the gallery
            if (enbBB)
            {
                if (activeBB == null || inactiveBB == null)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Please assign the bullet button textures, or disable the bullet buttons");
                    break;
                }
                else goto case 5;
            }
            else goto case 5;

        case 5:
            if (imgByPath)
            {
                if (!ImagesInsideProject && !ImagesOutsideProject)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Images by path is selected, but no location has been assigned. Assign the location, or select individual images instead");
                    break;
                }
                //Only occurs if user fiddles with undocumented settings.
                else if (AssignGallery== null)
                {
                    Debug.Log("File path is empty, please assign a location before continuing");
                    break;
                }
                else goto case 6;
            }
            else goto case 6;

        case 6:
            //if the fullscreen function is enabled, check if the textures for the minimize/maximize are set
            if (enbFullscreen)
            {
                if (fullScreenTex == null || fullScreenTexAlt == null)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Full screen has been assigned, but no textures have been. please assign textures for the full screen button, or disable full screen mode.");
                    break;
                }
                else goto case 7;
            }
            else goto case 7;

        case 7:
            CreateGallery();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this WinForm or WPF ?

Comment: @Heslacher As stated, it runs in unity3d (engine). It is GUI based form where a user has to fill in fields. Off which some may not be unassigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a switch here.

The easiest way is to just

```
if(emptyValueIsDetected)
{
    ShowErrorMessage
    return;
}
```

like

```
if (GalleryName == null || GalleryName == "Default")
{
    Debug.Log("No Gallery name assigned, please give the gallery a proper name");
    return;
}  
if (gallerySize.x == 0 || gallerySize.y == 0 || gallerySize.width == 0 || gallerySize.height == 0)
{
    Debug.Log("No gallery Sizes assigned, please set some sizes before creating a gallery");
    return;
}
```

and so on.

**Naming**

The name `indvImages` for a variable is not really meaningful. If **Mr.Maintainer** will inherit this code, he will need some time to understand what the variable should mean.

> ```
> //Enable Bullet Buttons for the gallery
> if (enbBB)
> ```

If you need a comment to explain what a variable stands for, you haven't named your variable in a meaningful way. A comment should only describe **why** something has been done, and not what it is `//This is a rectangle`.